# Set-theoretic intersection of affine open subschemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a separated scheme, $U,V \subseteq X$ open affine subschemes, $\Delta \colon X \to X \times X$ the diagonal morphism and $\pi_1, \pi_2 \colon X \times X \to X $ the natural projections, so that $\pi_i \circ \Delta = \text{id}_X$ for $i=1,2$.

It is easy to see by checking the universal property that $\pi_1^{-1}(U) \cap \pi_2^{-1}(V) \cong U \times V$. My question is, do we have
$$ \bigl|\Delta^{-1}\bigl(\underbrace{\pi_1^{-1}(U) \cap \pi_2^{-1}(V)}_{\cong \, U \times V}\bigr)\bigr| = U \cap V$$
as sets, as we would expect from the situation in the category of sets?
Notice that I'm not talking about bijection but equality of sets.

Comment: Correct. It's even true at the level of schemes. Moreover, no affineness or separation hypotheses are required – this is just category theory.

Comment: @ZhenLin: I don't see why its correct on a set-theoretical level. I mean when writing down the definition of the left hand set, I don't know how to get to the intersection without assuming that $X \times X$ is a cartesian product (which it isn't, right?)

Comment: Well, $U \times V$ is not a set-theoretic product either. But the difference "cancels out", so to speak.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, the product is constructed as $U \times V = U \times_{\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})} V$, as is $X \times X$. But I still don't see the set theoretic equality in question. I'm using the inverse image of $\Delta$ and the intersection $U \cap V$ as defined sets, not with a universal property.

Comment: It's a fact that $U \cap V \cong U \times_X V$. Use that.

Comment: Well, $\Delta^{-1}(\pi_1^{-1}(U) \cap \pi_2^{-1}(V)) = \Delta^{-1}(\pi_1^{-1}(U)) \cap \Delta^{-1}(\pi_2^{-1}(V)) = \operatorname{id}_X^{-1}(U) \cap \operatorname{id}_X^{-1}(V) = U \cap V$. Nothing really scheme-theoretic here, just the definition of $\Delta$.

Comment: @Hoot: Thank you! I'm sorry, it seems like I managed again to ask a triviality here, I just didn't see it.